# Python: Should I use a Class to wrap main?

Tags: python, class

I have a simple script that needs to poll for example 'weather data' every 24 hours using cron and dump the output to a DB.

What would be the most Pythonic way of implementing this?

I do however plan on using a WeatherRecord class used inside the parsing which is responsible for cleaning and modifying the raw input to the format required.

The second method below just feels like wrapping "main" in a class without adding any benefit.

Thanks for any comments

### Function version:

**file: bin/import-weather**

```
from weather.weather import import_weather()

def main()
    import_weather()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**file: weather/weather.py**

```
def import_weather():
    raw_weather = get_weather('http://weather.is.here/')
    parsed_weather = parse_weather(raw_weather)
    db_connection = DbConnection.getClient()
    write_weather_to_db(parsed_weather, db_connection)
```

### Class version:

**file: bin/import-weather**

```
from weather.weather import WeatherImporter

def main():
    weather = WeatherImporter()
    weather.parse_weather()
    weather.write_to_db()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**file: weather/weather.py**

```
class WeatherImporter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db_connection = DbConnection.getClient()
        self.url = 'http://weather.is.here/'
        self.raw_weather = self._get_weather()  # list of dict
        self.parsed_weather = None              # list of WeatherRecord

    def _get_weather(self):
        print(self.url)
        return ["{JSON Data}"]

    def parse_weather(self):
        self.parsed_weather = self.raw_weather

    def write_to_db(self):
        print(self.parsed_weather)
        pass
```

Comment: Think outside the “box”: Is your code only ever going to be used as the main entry point, or would it make sense to consume it from another Python script which has its own `main` and might run your `WeatherImporter` stuff separately (e.g. think of a GUI that allows you to get the weather data separately from storing it to the database). If the parsing and writing-to-database process is always a fixed sequence, then it does not make sense to split it up in a class (actually, that’s also an anti-pattern called [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/)).

Comment: (btw. an easy way to fix the temporal coupling in your `WeatherImporter` would be to remove the weather state from the class, i.e. remove the `raw_weather` and `parsed_weather`. Then, make `get_weather` fetch the raw weather and already parse it (no need to expose unparsed objects) and return that. Modify `write_to_db` then to take the parsed weather. That way, there is never any weather data inside your class, and the dependencies are all clear from the method signatures.)